# How to write Command in Console in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: windows, curl, console, cmd

For push messages from server I downloaded curl from [Link](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html). And in next step I would like to run the following command on the console:

```
D:\cURL>curl https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin -d Email=<C2DM Sender Account> -d "Passwd=<password>" -d accountType=GOOGLE -d source=org.examples.mobilepushplugin.example -d service=ac2dm –k
```

Can anyone help me to run the command on the console? What am I supposed to do? I am using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

As to my knowledge, Eclipse has no integrated command line interface. You are talking about the command line of your operating system. As `D:\` appears in your command, I'm assuming you are on Microsoft Windows.

To execute the command above, press `Windows + R`, enter `cmd` and hit enter to open the command line. If you installed curl in `D:\cURL` make sure your working directory is correct. Otherwise use the [`CD`](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) command for changing your working directory. Now you can enter your command (everything *after* `D:\cURL>`) and run it.

Comment: hi phineas I downloaded Curl from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) as a Zip and extracted after that i opend cmd prompt and make the current directory as d:\curl> and type the curl cmd but shows error like "D:\curl-7.24.0>curl
'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.".What i have to do to run command?

Comment: I don't have access to a window machine right now. First thing you should try is including the complete filename - curl.exe - in your command. If it doesn't work, try prepending `./`. `.` always points to the current directory and tells the cmd where exactly `curl` could be found.

Comment: Another possible way for invoking curl by addding it to the PATH variable (works with your original command) can be found here: http://superuser.com/questions/134685/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console

Comment: I downloaded curl while run the command there is no error but it produces Html code like `<HTML> ` `<HEAD> ` `<TITLE>Movedemporarily</TITLE>'
`</HEAD>`
`<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">`
`<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>`
`The document has moved <A HREF="https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin">here</A>.`
`</BODY>`
`</HTML>    ` what is the  probelm?i can' get Auth Id

Comment: As said, the resource moved temporarily. Read the developer documentation from Google and if you still encounter problems write another specific question. Invoking curl is solved. Furthermore I'm not sure if your command will work. Stuff like `org.examples.mobilepushplugin.example` clearly indicate that the command is an example and may need to be customized to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`System.in.read();` and it's brothers will let you read from the console in Eclipse.